# C# DataSet.Relations: How to use DataSet Relations?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have 3 tables and I have made relations to each of them.

let say: 
table 1 has:
aID, bID, cID, someText and someNumber

table 2 has:
bID, txtValueTable2, someText

table 3 has:
cID, txtValueTable3, someText

some code:

```
ds.Relations.Add("BrandNameStr", ds.Tables[1].Columns["bID"], ds.Tables[0].Columns["bID"]);
            ds.Relations.Add("IngredientStr", ds.Tables[2].Columns["cID"], ds.Tables[0].Columns["cID"]);
```

Now I want to use the columns off all 3 tables to make 1 dataset, but I don't know how?

The dataset must have the following columns:
aID, txtValueTable2, txtValueTable3, someText and someNumber

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/illustrateshowtospecifyandusearelationshipbetweentwoDataTableobjects.htm) there is a good example.

In few words you have to use [DataTabel.GetChildRows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbt8xha8.aspx) method.

[Here](http://pastie.org/2643234) are working example

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to know how to get an DataSet with this new column layout. This example only prints the relations, that is easy to do. I'm struggling with building the new DataSet.

Comment: i think you can't get the dataset without write some code, and the peace of code i show you point in the right way... instead of print the value of the child rows you can create new datatable and add the child rows. So you have to build a new dataset with new datatable that contains all the columns you want, and add the data row at run-time... or a simple way is to use a master / detail datagrid and bind the dataset with relations

Comment: OK, this example isn't clear for me enough, I still don't know how to built a new DataSet? I'm also not afraid to write code. But I don't hope when I have 100 columns and only the 2nd and 3rd column has to be replaced with the columns from the other tables that I have to write 100 times "column.add()"?

Comment: The example is now missing

Answer (score -1):

Hi you need to change by this:

ds.Relations.Add("BrandNameStr",ds.Tables[0].Columns["bID"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["bID"]);

Comment: add comment explaining your reason for this change.

Comment: No, Add method is defined as: Add(<relationName>, <parentColumn>, <childColumn>). And in this situation, Tables[1] and Tables[2] are parent tables. So asker is using this method in the right way.